# 2D Engine for iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, open-source, 2d-engine

I have a pretty simple 2D flash game. It's a jump n run sidescroller and I want to port it to the iPhone.
But what is the best way to do it? There is Adobe Flash Pro CS5 but I'd rather program it from the scratch in an iPhone environment.
Are there any top games done by open source framekworks? Which is the best way to go?

Answer (score 2):

If your main concern is easily porting it, then I'd have a look at [corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/). Apparently porting from flash is very easy, and they have guides for ActionScript to Corona (Lua) conversions. It's not free or open source, but there is a 30 Day trial period available.

Answer (score 0):

check [cocos2d](http://cocos2d-iphone.org)